# How do I import selenium webdriver tests from one Python file to another?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pytest

I'm incredibly new to separating modules. I have this long Python script that I want to separate into different files by class and run them collectively **in the same browser instance/window**.  The reason for this is all the tests are reliant on being logged into the same session.  I'd like to do a universal setUp, then login, and then pull the different tests in one after another.
Folder structure is:

```
ContentCreator
- main.py
- _init_.py
- Features
     - login.py
     - pytest.py
     - _init_.py
```

Here is my code:

login.py

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

class logIn(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def test_login(self):
        """Login"""
        driver.get("sign_in_url")

        # load username and pw through a json file
        with open('path/to/file.json', 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)

        # login
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(config['user']['name'])
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(config['user']['password'])
        driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print("You are Logged In!")
```

pytest.py

```
import time
import unittest
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from displays import DISPLAY_TYPES, DISPLAY_NAMES

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.get("url")

class createContent(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def test_add_required(self):
        """Test adding all the required fields across all sites:"""
        for i in range(1):
            """This is the number of each type of article that will be created."""

            for i in range(1):
                """This is how many different article types that will be created."""
                print("create new content")
                time.sleep(1)
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("Content").click()
                time.sleep(1)
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("Create New").click()

                print("select a display type:")
                display = DISPLAY_TYPES 
                display_type = driver.find_element_by_id(display[i])
                display_type.click()

                names = (DISPLAY_NAMES[i])
                print(names), (" created and saved successfully!")
     @classmethod
     def tearDownClass(cls):
         # close the browser window
         driver.quit()

     def is_element_present(self, how, what):
          """
          Helper method to confirm the presence of an element on page
         :params how: By locator type
         :params what: locator value
         """
         try:
             driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
         except NoSuchElementException:
             return False
         return True
```

main.py

```
import unittest
from HtmlTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner
from features.login import logIn
from features.pytest import createContent

login_script = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(logIn)
add_pytest = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(createContent)

# create a test suite combining all tests
test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([login, add_pytest])

# create output
runner = HTMLTestRunner(output='Test Results')

# run the suite
runner.run(test_suite)
```

When running the above code it opens two browser sessions, and only the login script get executed.  The test fails do to not finding the elements outlined in the next script.

EDIT:
Alfonso Jimenez or anyone else, here's what I have so far...

Folder structure:
- Files
         - singleton.py
         - singleton2.py

New Singleton code...

singleton.py:

```
from robot.api import logger
from robot.utils import asserts
from selenium import webdriver

class Singleton(object):

instance = None

def __new__(cls, base_url, browser='chrome'):

    if cls.instance is None:
        i = object.__new__(cls)
        cls.instance = i
        cls.base_url = base_url
        cls.browser = browser

        if browser == "chrome":
            # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
            cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        else:
            # Sorry, we can't help you right now.
            asserts.fail("Support for Chrome only!")

    else:

        i = cls.instance

    return i
```

singleton2.py:

```
import time
import json
from datetime import datetime
from singleton import Singleton

driver = Singleton('base_url')

def teardown_module(module):
driver.quit()

class logIn(object):
def test_login(self):
    """Login"""
    driver.get("url.com")

    # load username and pw through a json file
    with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    # login
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(config['user']['name'])
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(config['user']['password'])
    driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    print("You are Logged In!")

    # take screenshot
    driver.save_screenshot('path/screenshot_{}.png'.format(datetime.now()))
```

The result is that an instance of Chrome kicks off, but nothing happens.  The base_url (or any other URL defined in my test) doesn't come up.  The blank window is all I get.  Any insights on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating two times the selenium driver.

If you want to keep the same session opened you should pass the same object to both scripts, or import it, what it could be valid, however it would be a more dirty solution.

The best thing to do is create a **singleton** class to initiate the driver. Once you have done this, every time you create an object from this class you will get the a unique object of webdriver.

You can get an example from [this answer](https://gist.github.com/omaciel/2625008).

You can also check more about singleton instances, they're a very common and very useful. You can check [here](https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2012/04/26/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-python/).

Comment: Thank you for the response... a few questions:
Do you need robot for singleton classes?
Which py file would I implement the singleton class?  Or does it get it's own?

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand what you mean with robot, perhaps the [testing framework](http://robotframework.org/)?

You can write the singleton class wherever you want to. You will have to import the class from that place and then instantiate the object. Ex:

lib/singleton_web_driver.py

```
from robot.api import logger
from robot.utils import asserts

from selenium import webdriver

class Singleton(object):

    instance = None

    def __new__(cls, base_url, browser='firefox'):

        if cls.instance is None:
            i = object.__new__(cls)
            cls.instance = i
            cls.base_url = base_url
            cls.browser = browser

            if browser == "firefox":
                # Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
                cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            elif browser == "remote":
                # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
                cls.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
            else:
                # Sorry, we can't help you right now.
                asserts.fail("Support for Firefox or Remote only!")

        else:

            i = cls.instance

        return i
```

and then in every script youre going to need the webdriver:

test_script_file.py

```
from lib.singleton_web_driver import Singleton

driver = Singleton('base_url')
```

This just a dummy code, I dindnt test it. The important point is to create the class with the *_new_* method where you can check if the class has already been called. The import is just like any other class import, you write the class in a folder and then import it in the scripts youre going to use.

Comment: Alfonso,  I attempted what you suggested.  Please see the 'EDIT' portion of my original post.  I would appreciate it if you could try to help let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: I just saw the problem, you're not instantiating the driver but the class. See my edit to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My solution was just to initiate the driver in the main file and then to use this driver within the imported files and functions. Like in this example to change `createContent(unittest.TestCase)` to `createContent(unittest.TestCase, driver)`